# Keep SignalR listening forever in a code that is not always running

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, raspberry-pi, signalr

I am using signalR core in asp.net core application. The code does not contain any infinite loop thus it will end in sometime. How can i keep signalR listen forever and execute a function when a message is received without using an infinite loop? I am running the code on raspberry pi so hardware resources are limited and a loop is not a good choice;

the code worked when the part that needs data from signalR is put in a while(true); but it is heavy for the raspberry pi

```
connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl("http://192.168.1.20:1234/getChoice")
            .Build();
connection.Closed += async (error) =>
{
   await Task.Delay(new Random().Next(0, 5) * 1000);
   await connection.StartAsync();
};
   connection.On<string, string>("ReceiveMessage", (user, message) =>
{
   controlSensors(message.ToString());
});
await connection.StartAsync();
```

I want the code to keep listening for any new choice to execute the intended function in controlSensors method; The actual result is that the code directly finishes because obviously it did not receive any message in the second that the code is launched

Comment: In short, you cant. If the code isn't running, your connection closes

Comment: That looks like client code rather than server code (your app is acting as a SingalR client, making a connection, not a server that receives connections)

Comment: Is the application really a client to some other SignalR server? That’s a bit odd way, usually they’re servers on a web application. And busy loop of course will take all the CPU it can get so that’s not an option ever.

Comment: If you use SignalR correctly it will listen when the app is running and execute methods on the hub (server-side) and execute javascript in the browser (client-side). If you need to manually listen with SignalR you're not using it correctly.

Comment: It is client code

Comment: What I really want is that another client send the commands wanted to control some sensors

Comment: @Joelius You have a point. I think I am doing it wrong. I am gonna do what you said and return with the results.

Comment: If you want it to listen for connections, it needs to be a SignalR server, not a client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Code was hosted on a server and this worked. It should be server side.

Answer (score 2):

You can write `Console.Read()` or `Console.ReadLine()` in that while loop at end of program. In that way while loop will not consume CPU resources.

```
while(true)
{
    Console.Read();
}
```